Moving the focus in the series of EditText when Autofill event occur
I tried to move the edittext focus to one to another (next) when selecting the autofill (suggestions from top of the keyboard). But it is not moving properly.
The approach I tried is mentioned below.
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun setOnAutofillCompleteListener(currentEditText: EditText, nextEditText: EditText) {
        currentEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            autofillManager.let {
                if(!hasFocus) return@setOnFocusChangeListener
                autofillManager.registerCallback(object : AutofillManager.AutofillCallback() {
                    override fun onAutofillEvent(view: View, event: Int) {
                        if (event == EVENT_INPUT_UNAVAILABLE || event == EVENT_INPUT_HIDDEN) {
                                nextEditText.requestFocus()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

In onCreate of the Activity called the below method
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

private fun registerAutoCompleteListener() {
    setOnAutofillCompleteListener(binding.firstName,binding.lastName)
    setOnAutofillCompleteListener(binding.lastName,binding.emailAddress)
    setOnAutofillCompleteListener(binding.emailAddress,binding.phoneNumber)
    setOnAutofillCompleteListener(binding.phoneNumber,binding.password)
    setOnAutofillCompleteListener(binding.password,binding.passwordConfirmPassword)
}

Initialized the AutofillManager system service like lateinit property
autofillManager = getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)

For example, on selecting the (autofill) suggestion (Firstname Lastname), the first and second edittext should be filled and the focus move to next email address edittext.

Not working properly, what exactly is wrong? Please edit your question accordingly
